# LDAP connection with C# desktop application

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am pretty new to working with Active directories and LDAP, have been going through some articles and trying to establish a connection with LDAP..

I have LDAP URL and Base DN(Base Distinguished Name) URL.. I was able to establish a connection with the LDAP URL but when I am trying to establish connection with Base DN URL i am getting below error..

A referral was returned from the server

```
string username = “ldapuser”;
string password = “prime812”;
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(“LDAP://AM-LDAP-SN.ams.com/CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=AMS,dc=com:389”, username,password);
DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
SearchResult res = deSearch.FindOne();
```

Instead of the Base DN URL when I am querying the below LDAP URL it’s working fine..

```
LDAP://AM-LDAP-SN.ams.com:389
```

Also would like to know what is the difference between both the URL’s , LDAP url and Base DN url..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A referral means: "I can't answer your question, but I know who can." It's a way for a server to direct you to the right place when you're connecting to the wrong place. But it is also something unexpected, which is why it throws an exception.

I suspect your LDAP path is just wrong. The LDAP path should be constructed like this:

```
LDAP://server/distinguishedName
```

Both the server and distinguished name (DN) are optional, but you need at least one. If only the server is specified, then the default DN for that server is used (the root of the domain).  That's what is happening when you use `LDAP://AM-LDAP-SN.ams.com:389`. If only the DN is specified, then your computer has to know which server to talk to for that DN. That only happens if your computer is joined to that domain or a trusted domain.

If you specify a port, that should be part of the server information, not the DN. I think that's where your mistake is. Your code should look like this:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://AM-LDAP-SN.ams.com:389/CN=Users,DC=ms,DC=ds,DC=AMS,dc=com", username,password);
```

Notice the `:389` is after the domain name, not the DN.

I tested this myself (putting the port number after the DN) and I got a referral exception too. You will probably notice the `ExtendedErrorMessage` of the exception object showing that it's pointing you to `AM-LDAP-SN.ams.com:389`.

But 389 is the default port, so you can remove it entirely. You only need to specify the port if it's not 389.

Comment: My port number is 389, as I cannot paste my code I just used a random number here in my question  but in my actual code it’s 389...

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: My answer still applies. You put the port in the wrong place. But if the port is 389, then you don't need to specify it at all. You can just remove it.